# Differenza nel significato e nell'uso di "fidanzato"

Tags: word-usage

Ho un dubbio sulla parola **fidanzato**. In inglese o anche in tedesco lo si traduce come *fiancé* oppure *der Verlobte*. 
In entrambi i casi lo si intende come una persona che **è prossima al matrimonio**.

Io però penso che in italiano venga anche e molto spesso usato quando una persona è in una relazione seria, anche se non c'è ancora stata alcuna proposta di matrimonio. Mi sbaglio? 
Non mi pare che in italiano si riferisca esclusivamente a chi si sta per sposare.

È possibile che l'originale significato della parola sia "prossimo al matrimonio" ma che sempre più l'uso che se ne fa stia cambiando?

Comment: Del resto mi suonerrebbe abbastanza ridicolo continuare a usare esclusivamente la parola "ragazzo" .. immagino una 45 enne che mi presenta il suo "ragazzo"...Uhm. Mi parrebbe ridicolo o solo un tentativo di mostrarsi giovanile..risultando però proprio imbarazzante.

Comment: A me pare che l'intera usanza del fidanzamento sia diversa...In Italia non esiste il clichè dell'uomo che si inginocchia e dà l'anello di fidanzamento chiedendo *mi vuoi sposare?* Tendenzialmente è una decisione che viene presa assieme, e dunque non c'è un istante di tempo in cui si passa da *ragazzo/a* (in realtà io personalmente preferisco usare *moroso/a*) a *promesso sposo/a*. Nelle altre lingue credo (da ignorante) che si sia mantenuta la distinzione di significato anche perchè quel genere di usanza esiste ancora, mentre da noi la situazione è più ambigua (e dunque anche il termine lo è)

Comment: Nell'esempio specificato da E.V. mi permetto di suggerire la parola 'compagno', usata dalle mie parti spesso in questi casi.

Answer (score 5):

Io ho sempre sentito usare i termini "fidanzato"/"fidanzata" nel senso di "persone che hanno una relazione senza essere sposati", indipendentemente da futuri piani di matrimonio.

Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fidanzato/) dice:

> Che o chi intrattiene una relazione amorosa (ed ha eventualmente
>   scambiato promessa di matrimonio; in tal caso, come sost., promesso
>   sposo, promessa sposa)

Non so se ci sia mai stato un tempo in cui "fidanzato" implicava necessariamente che dovesse seguire il matrimonio; se ci fu, non sono abbastanza vecchio da ricordarlo.

Comment: Confermo tutto, ma aggiungo che il significato originario di “fidanzato” è proprio e solo “promesso sposo”, dove la “fidanza” era la fiducia, la promessa che ci si scambiava. Per esempio lo Zingarelli del 1948 (che oltre a essere bello da sfogliare è utile proprio per verificare accezioni più vecchie rispetto a quelle insorte dopo) registra esclusivamente “Promesso sposo. *la –*, La giovine che ha dato e ricevuto promessa di matrimonio”.

Comment: Direi che l'uso di “fidanzato/a” per indicare un compagno/a più o meno fisso (e in certi casi addirittura un “amico” non ufficiale) sia nato per colmare la mancanza di termini moderni per rapporti non basati sul matrimonio (visto che, come commenta giustamente @E.V., “ragazzo/a” non va sempre bene).

Comment: Il significato di "engaged" nell'inglese è che le persone intendono sposarsi.

Comment: @echristopherson grazie, non lo sapevo. Correggo la risposta.